# Javascript jQuery Error Overload Ajax Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two buttons. One Button refreshes the table (html table) with a ajax php request. And there is another button to refresh it every 10 seconds. If I try to access the document it throw a lot of errors that I don't know about how to solve the problem.

My Javascript Code is here:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#reloadLoginActivities").click(function(){
            $("#loginActivities").load("https://www.prodigy-official.de/resources/php/website_utilities.php", {
            function: "loadTenLatestLoginActivities"
        });
    });

    $("#liveUpdateLoginActivities").click(setInterval(function(){
         $("#loginActivities").load("https://www.prodigy-official.de/resources/php/website_utilities.php", {
            function: "loadTenLatestLoginActivities2"
          },10000);
      }));
   });
</script>
```

I get a lot of errors in : https://prnt.sc/pp33s1

My jQuery File is here: https://www.prodigy-official.de/resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your formation is not correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reloadLoginActivities").click(function(){
        $("#loginActivities").load("https://www.prodigy-official.de/resources/php/website_utilities.php", {
            function: "loadTenLatestLoginActivities"
        });
    });


$("#liveUpdateLoginActivities").click(setInterval(function(){
        $("#loginActivities").load("https://www.prodigy-official.de/resources/php/website_utilities.php", {
            function: "loadTenLatestLoginActivities2"

        });
    }, 10000));
});
```

Comment: how can I change the text of the button with the id "liveUpdateLoginActivities" ?! if I execute the second method and before I wait for the 10 seconds?

Comment: Yeah, I this here works: $("#liveUpdateLoginActivities").text("Stop Live Update"); but, he execute this after the 10 seconds. I want to execute this first and then wait 10 seconds. HOW

Comment: @1ntelligence0 Please check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reloadLoginActivities").click(function () {
        $("#loginActivities").load("https://www.prodigy-official.de/resources/php/website_utilities.php", {
            function: "loadTenLatestLoginActivities"
        });
    });


    $("#liveUpdateLoginActivities").click(liveActivityHandler);

    function liveActivityHandler () {
        $("#liveUpdateLoginActivities").text("Stop Live Update");
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#loginActivities").load("https://www.prodigy-official.de/resources/php/website_utilities.php", {
                function: "loadTenLatestLoginActivities2"

            });
        }, 10000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by creating a native javascript function and apply that on that button with a attribute: onclick="myFunction()" ;) but thanks!